# how to count the number of character in each line and size of file in byte from file

Tags: c++

i want to know can i count the number of character in each line 
and the size of file in byte that  1 character occupies 1 byte ?

which i count the number of lines from file

```
string name;
string line;

cout<<"enter the name of file"<<endl;

cin>>name;

ifstream inf;

inf.open(name.c_str());

//if(!inf)
//{
//  cout<<"File could not be opened."<<endl;
//  void menu();

//  exit(1);
//}


 if (inf.is_open())
```

{

```
  while ( getline (inf,line) )
{
  cout << line << endl;
  number_of_lines++;
}

inf.close();
 }
 else 
     cout<<"File could not be opened."<<endl;
```

Comment: Does this count the lines correctly? And do you know how to count the characters in a line?

Comment: yes  it count correctly ,no i do not know how to count the characters in line

Comment: You save the line as a `string`. Is that a `std::string`, or your own creation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every 1 character in a text file takes 1 byte size on disk.

```
size_t sizeOfFile = 0;
while ( getline (inf,line) )
{
  for (char i : line)
    sizeOfFile += 1; //better yet, sizeOfFile += sizeof(i);
  cout << line << endl;
  sizeOfFile += 2; //don't forget the newline character '\n'
  number_of_lines++;
}
```

Comment: Things can get pretty complicated then. Best option would be opening and reading the file in binary mode.

Comment: what do mean by   for (char i : line)

Comment: @omar it's a c++11 feature: ranged based for: see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) or tutorial [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html)

Comment: Yes, as bolov said, it's a c++11 feature. The equivalent would be: `for (int j =0; j < strlen(line); j++){ char i = line[j]; }`

Comment: i can not write char i = line[j]; because i can not convert line from string to char

Comment: But a string is an (null-terminated) array of characters! An element of a string is therefore a character ;)

Comment: also about finding the size of file can we use structure ?? if yes how ??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'structure'? C structs? ie `struct foo{int a, v, c, d;};` ?